# Need to load Javascript lib's and support files dynamically by another javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, angular

My task: If I include a single javascript file (vlib.js) it should automatically include all supporting JS lib in to landing document.

**What I did:** I have a string array which contains all list of JS file paths to append. I have a function declared in Vlib.js as a global function. It appends all the files correctly, but the problem is I'm getting some errors!

The appending starts with some library files like angular.min,... jquery.min.. bootstrap.. and my custom JS files. Even though I append them in the correct order I'm getting errors like angular not defined and others errors which shouldn't have come if it is loaded in correct order. My team mate says even if put it in correct order it might finish load randomly like angular related files loading before angular.min. So is there any way I can load a script and then move on to appending to other js only when the first one is loaded? I have to do this using native JS.

im using this code

```
function populateJsDynamicX() {

  for (var index = 0; index < jsSet.length; index++) {

    source = jsSet[index];

    if (jsSet[index].includes('.js')) {

        console.log(source);

        var scriptTag = document.createElement('script'), // create a script tag        

        firstScriptTag = document.getElementById('viewerHandle'); // find the first script tag in the document

        scriptTag.src = source; // set the source of the script to your script

        scriptTag.type = "text/javascript";

        //firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(scriptTag, firstScriptTag); // append the script to the DOM

        document.head.appendChild(scriptTag);

        (document, 'script');

    } else {

        console.log(source);

        var scriptTag = document.createElement('link'), // create a script tag        

        firstScriptTag = document.getElementById('viewerHandle'); // find the first script tag in the document

        scriptTag.href = source; // set the source of the script to your script

        scriptTag.type = "text/css";

        scriptTag.rel = "stylesheet";

        //firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(scriptTag, firstScriptTag); // append the script to the DOM

        document.head.appendChild(scriptTag);

        (document, 'script');

    }

  }

  console.log(jsSet.length);
}
```

Some other guys said `$.getScript` will get the job done, but I want to do this by native JS, can u guys tell me where I'm wrong?

I get error like this:

[image: JavaScrip Error]

Comment: I recommend you to use LAB library

Comment: If you use angular I recommend building the rest of your logic in Angular too, instead of using separate js files... also it doesn’t make sense to use both angular and jQuery since both have different ways of manipulating the DOM, you will get conflicts and errors.